# how do you generate samples from the logistic CDF using the inverse-CDF method

Tags: r, sampling, cdf

My question is how to generate a sample in R from a logistic CDF with the inverse CDF method. The logistic density is p(θ) = exp(θ)/(1 + exp(θ))^2

Here is the algorithm for that method:

```
1: for t = 1 to T do
2: sample q(t) ∼ Unif(0, 1)
3: θ(t) ← F^−1(q(t))
4: end for
```

Here is my code but it just generates a vector of the same number. The result should be log-concave but obviously it would not be that if I put it in the histogram, so what is the problem?:

First define T as the number of draws you're taking from uniform distribution

```
T<-100000
sample_q<-runif(T,0,1)
```

It seems like `plogis` will give you the cumulative distribution function, so I suppose I can just take its inverse:

```
generate_samples_from_logistic_CDF <- function(p) {
   for(t in length(T)) 
       cdf<-plogis((1+exp(p)/(exp(p))))
   inverse_cdf<-(1/cdf)
   return(inverse_cdf)
}
```

should generate_samples_from_logistic_CDF(sample_q)
but instead it only gives me the same value for everything

Answer (score 3):

Since the inverse CDF is already coded in R as `qlogis()`, this should work:

```
qlogis(runif(100000))
```

or if you want to do it "by hand" rather than using the built-in `qlogis()`, you can use `R <- runif(100000); log(R/(1-R))`

Note that `rlogis(100000)` should be more efficient.

One of your confusions is that "inverse" in the algorithm description above doesn't mean  the multiplicative inverse or reciprocal (i.e. 1/x), but rather the *function inverse* (which in this case is `log(q/(1-q))`)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried qlogis earlier, and it works now with the correct cdf function (exp(p)/(1+exp(p))^2), but it seems also to generate a vector of negative numbers. Is this correct? Could I also just use rlogis?                                                                                                                 
T<-100000
sample_q<-runif(T,0,1).                                               generate_samples_from_logistic_CDF<-function(p) {
   for(t in length(T)) 
     inverse_cdf<-qlogis((exp(p)/(1+exp(p))^2))
     return(inverse_cdf)
 }